# Mysql select sum() from another table

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum, left-join

I have this tables :

**Table: Articles**

```
   id   |   title   |   display   |
 -----------------------------------
    1   |   Fkekc   |      1      |
    2   |   ldsdf   |      1      |
    3   |   OTRld   |      0      |
    4   |   QCRSA   |      1      |
```

**Table: Likes**

```
   id  |  article_id |   like   |  type
 ----------------------------------------
    1   |      1     |   121    |   1
    2   |      1     |   652    |   2
    3   |      2     |   12     |   1
    4   |      1     |   5      |   3
```

i want get this result:

```
Article [1] => 778
Article [2] => 12
Article [3] => 0
Article [4] => 0
```

I use LEFT JOIN between two tables but this return records per `likes` table. so i get three record of article 1

My code:

```
 SELECT articles.*,likes.like FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN `likes` ON articles.id=likes.article_id WHERE display='1'
```

I know that i must use `SUM()` but i didn't know how use it

With your answers i find that i must use this:

```
SELECT articles.*, sum(likes.like) as likesSum FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN `likes`ON articles.id=likes.article_id WHERE display='1' GROUP BY articles.id
```

But i want to set filter in query. so use this :

```
SELECT articles.*, sum(likes.like) as likesSum FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN `likes`ON articles.id=likes.article_id WHERE display='1' && likesSum>='100' GROUP BY articles.id
```

But above code doesn't return any result

Comment: replace likes.like with sum(likes.like) as total_like

Comment: @BikashP i use it but my code return just one record `article1` that have total likes `790`

Comment: group by article_id?

Comment: @Ebadghafoory check answer and reply if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query

```
SELECT articles.*,COALESCE(sum(likes.like),0) as total_like  FROM 
`articles` LEFT JOIN `likes` ON articles.id=likes.article_id group by   
articles.id
```

Output is [image]

Comment: this code work perfect. but i want use filter in my query. so i use this SELECT articles.*, COALESCE(sum(likes.like),0) as total_like FROM articles` LEFT JOIN likesON articles.id=likes.article_id WHERE display='1' && total_like>='100' GROUP BY articles.id` .... but this is not return result

Comment: Not  && total like write having total_like

Comment: where display='1' having total_like >100

Comment: Thank you and for multi filter such as total_like >100 AND total_like <400 I must use two `having` OR use &&

Comment: having total_like >100 AND total_like <400

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT articles.*, sum(likes.like) as likesSum FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN `likes`ON articles.id=likes.article_id WHERE display='1' GROUP BY articles.id
```

Comment: `likes.sum` is true ?!

Comment: Made a mistake. Corrected it.

Comment: this code work perfect. but i want use filter in my query. so i use this `SELECT articles.*, sum(likes.like) as likesSum FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN `likes`ON articles.id=likes.article_id WHERE display='1' && likesSum>='100' GROUP BY articles.id` .... but this is not return result

Comment: I think that you're using the wrong syntax for your purpose. We don't have any && in sql; use "and" instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you perfectly..

```
SELECT articles.id, sum(likes.like) from articles left join likes on (articles.id=likes.article_id) group by articles.id order by articles.id
```

See the use of SUM() with GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

You did everything right but only one this missing. You should have used group by

```
SELECT articles.*, likes.like 
FROM `articles` 
LEFT JOIN `likes` ON articles.id = likes.article_id 
WHERE display = '1' 
GROUP BY likes.article_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This visual representation is great to understand the joins: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins